# Django Chart.js ajax javascript "string data parsing error"

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, chart.js

I am creating chart web page through Django and Chart.js
(in the views.py of Django)

```
class ChartView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'graph.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ChartView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['labels'] = ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"]
        context['datas'] = [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3]
        return context
```

in the html file (template file)

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
var data = {
    labels: {{ labels }},
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "Site Registrations in the Last 30 Days",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: {{ datas }}
        }
    ]
};
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data);
});
</script>
```

The html page rendering is having error. (The page source looks like this)

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
var data = {
    labels: [u&#39;Red&#39;, u&#39;Blue&#39;, u&#39;Yellow&#39;, u&#39;Green&#39;, u&#39;Purple&#39;, u&#39;Orange&#39;],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "Site Registrations in the Last 30 Days",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3]
        }
    ]
};
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data);
});
</script>
```

Clearly, you can see that data : {{ datas }} are getting correct value. However, labels : {{ labels }} are getting wrong values. I do not understand how to parse the string in Ajax/javascript? Please let me know how to do it correctly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to output the whole labels list directly as a Javascript array, it may be better to build a Javascript array from the list:

```
var data = {
    labels: [{% for label in labels %}"{{ label }}", {% endfor %}],
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [`safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) template filter.

> `safe` marks a string as not requiring further HTML escaping prior to output.

Example:

```
{{ labels|safe }}
```

Comment: after using safe , This is rendering labels: [u'Red', u'Blue', u'Yellow', u'Green', u'Purple', u'Orange']. However, I want to render labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"]. Please let me know how to do it. Thank you

Comment: What python version are you using?

Comment: Python 2.7.10  and Django==1.11.16

Comment: I cannot reproduce that on my system. You can try fixing it by converting the list to json: `json.dumps(["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"])`. Import json before that.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your suggestion.
I just converted from

```
   python 2.7 to python 3.7
```

It works perfectly fine.